# adding "IMPORTANT!" alert to messages when sending it through webhook

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams

i'm using webhook to send certain alerts to a microsoft teams chat. i was wondering if there's a certain keyword i can add to my json to send the message as "Important!" or a markdown i can add to my message.

Answer (score 0):

!Important feature is a part of Microsoft Teams product & looks like it is not supported in Webhook messages.

However message cards supports Markdown & HTML, so you can format your cards accordingly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=connector-md%2Cconnector-html

Could you please raise a user voice here:
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new